# What is the best way to calculate distance travelled over a period of time?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to calculate the distance elapsed over a period of time in an app for the Android platform.
What is the best way to do this?
At the moment, I am implementing LocationListener interface.
I am overriding the method onLocationChanged

I am currently doing something like this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "onLocationChanged");


        old_location.set(new_location);
        new_location.set(location);
        totalDistanceElapsed += new_location.distanceTo(old_location);
```

}
So I am adding the distance from the old location point to the new location point ever time "onLocationChanged" is called.
Is this correct?
Do I need to do anything else?
Will this be accurate? If not, how can I make it more accurate? thanks

Comment: It depends, how much accurency do you want ? For me, the best way is to record the gps position every x times (for example 30s) and then calculate the distance. Depending of the context it could change... Maybe another way is to calculate the sample time based on the speed. I mean, if the speed is high you improve the sample rate :)

Comment: Good question. One property totalDistanceElapsed must have is that it doesn't increase when not moving. I am not sure how precise location is, so I would recommend a test where the phone is not moving and you verify that totalDistanceElapsed don't increase. If it is indeed increasing you could add a tolerance of 10m or something where you discard events if less than tolerance.

Comment: Thank you
Now I do not know how to "test where the phone is not moving"
Could you help again please? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial way to determine distance travelled over time would be to obtain fixes every second, and read and record the speed reported for each fix (in meters per second). Then your distance travelled is the sum of all the speeds over the period of time elapsed.

If you want to avoid counting "jitter" as movement (i.e. if the fixes are wandering about slowly because of GPS fix inaccuracies, but the device is actually stationary) you can set a velocity threshold, e.g. by ignoring speeds below a certain level, or if the heading is changing rapidly between fixes. These thresholds will probably depend on the GPS device used, and some devices have this kind of thing built in already (i.e. if the speed is too low they report 0 m/s).

It really does depend on the device, however. For examply, my early model Samsung Galaxy I9000  wanders about in a 20 meter radius area even in clear sky conditions at about half a meter per second, so if it sits stationary in a field for ten minutes the above algorithm would report it as having travelled 300m.