# Calculate distance travelled -Android

Tags: java, android

I have this code in my main activity which will show the location data in textviews:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);
    startactivity();
    }
```

startctivity function:

```
    private void startactivity() 
{

            GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);

            if(gps.canGetLocation())
            {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
            else
            {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

}
```

I have created a separate class GPSTracker.java for finding location.

canGetLocation() is a function which checks if there are any providers available.
getLatitude() finds the latitude and getLongitude() finds the longitude.

These functions work and I get the values in the 'latitude' and 'longitude' variables.

The onLocationChanged(Location location) is empty for now in the GPSTracker class.

I want to calculate the distance travelled by this method:
[What is the best way to calculate distance travelled over a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732040/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-distance-travelled-over-a-period-of-time)

But I'm confused by how the old_location and new_location variables are used.
How does that work and how can I implement that with my current functions/classes?

Answer (score 2):

To get the distance travelled you just have to sum the distance between the old_location and new_location. F.E. new_location is the location you actually receive from onLocationChanged. And it becomes the old_location if a new location is received and so on. You could use the [Location.distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) Method to get the distances between these two points.

Keep in mind that the GPS Signal has a variance of accuracy.

EDIT:

Because this topic is very broad try this:
Here's a good [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) to get in touch with the Location API. If you want to dive deeper try the [Google Samples](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Comment: Yea I understand the concept but I can't get through the coding part.
Where do I have to declare and initialize those locations. Which method returns the new location? Where I have to do that new to old thing? In onLocationChanged() or startactivity(). Will the onLocationChanged still work if its in a different class? because we don't have to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your entire checking within `onLocationChanged()` and then you could check against thresholds since you would be drifting even when standing still for periods of time.  Perhaps only add to distance travelled when the difference is greater than 100 meters from a previous position.

Then setup a listener and have the class with `onLocationChanged()` update through the listener back to your activity.  This could be used to then update perhaps something as simple as a textview at the top of your screen that is displaying distance travelled.

Not sure if there is a built-in conversion from latitute-longitude to metric measurements, if so you can use that.  Otherwise you might need to see what quick formulation can be done to convert between GPS coordinates to distance travelled.